# Zipkin Server not logging Http request traces in debug mode

Tags: zipkin, distributed-tracing

I have enabled the distributed tracing using Zipkin tracer as mentioned in 
https://github.com/openzipkin/brave for the microservices.

I could see the service call info and time taken in the Zipkin server running in local machine.

I have usecase to capture the trace logs of every http requests alongside the JSON messages (with the Trace ,span and parent IDs) received by to Zipkin server from the client.

Zipkin server is started in debug mode to enable the logging, however the http requests are not logged in the Zipkin server logs.

Can someone throw some light please?